# Prepend XML Declaration to Flex e4x XML Object

Tags: xml, apache-flex, e4x

How do you add an XML declaration - < ?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"? > - to a Flex XML object? The same thing you could do with the old XML - new XMLDocument class and the xmlDecl property.

Answer (score 0):

Seems that new `XML` class always ignores this processing instruction.

If it's true then you need to add `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>` string manually when it is outputted to a file or sent to the server.